# Is there a "standard" basic class in python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am looking for a way to create a basic python "object" which I can externally assign attributes to.
Currently I am doing it the following way:

I define an empty class with

```
class C(object):
    pass
```

and then I instantiate an object and assign attributes like this:

```
c = C()
c.attr = 2
```

#### Coming to my question

Is there a way to instantiate an empty class object, which I can then assign attributes like shown above without defining a `class C`?

Is there maybe an other better way to accomplish what I am after?

Comment: One better way seems to be to just go ahead and program in JavaScript directly. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a flexible container that has no methods and can take attributes with arbitrary names. That's a `dict`.

```
d = dict()
d['myattr'] = 42
```

If you prefer the attribute syntax that you get with a class (`c.myattr = 42`), then use a class just as per the code in your question.

Comment: @Woltan: in fact, a class is just a wrapper around a `dict` with a bunch of implementation details and a way of translating from attribute `.foo` syntax to dict lookup `['foo']`.

Comment: @katrielalex not quite; there are also optimizations based on the fact that attribute names are expected to be strings.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to instantiate an empty class object, which I can then assign attributes like shown above without defining a class C?

Yes:

```
>>> C = type("C", (object,), {})
>>> c = C()
>>> c.attr = 2
```

But as you can see, it's not much of an improvement, and the end result is the same -- it's just another way of creating the same class `C`.

**Addendum:**

You can make it prettier by "hiding" it in a function:

```
def attr_holder(cls=type("C", (object,), {})):
    return cls()

c = attr_holder()
c.attr = 2
```

Though this is just reinventing the wheel -- replace the two line function with

```
class attr_holder(object):
    pass
```

and it'll work exactly the same, and we've come full circle. So: go with what David or Reorx suggests.

Comment: Too bad, I though there is an equivalent python class to `Object` in C#.

Comment: @Woltan Well, there is `object`, which is the base class of all python objects, but as you've probably discovered, you can't dynamically set the attributes of `object()`. The only use of `object()` that I've found is as a sentinel.

Answer (score 2):

I had come to the same question long ago, and then create this class to use in many of my projects:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    """
    retrieve value of dict in dot style
    """
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError('has no attribute %s' % key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __delattr__(self, key):
        try:
            del self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

    def __str__(self):
        return '<DotDict %s >' % self.__to_dict()

    def __to_dict(self):
        return dict(self)
```

When I want a object to store data or want to retrieve value easily from a dict, I always use this class.

Additionally, it can help me serialize the attributes that I set in the object, and reversely get the original dict when needed.

So I think this may be a good solution in many situations, though other tricks look simple,
they are not very helpful further.

Comment: This is a nice solution! However, it is generally frowned upon to create custom attributes and methods starting _and ending_ with `__`. Use attributes starting with a single underscore to indicate a method _should_ not be used externally (but may be), and two starting underscores to make it ["private"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Comment: @lazyr Totally agree :). At first I just want to prevent possible conflicts that may happen when set attribute starting with single underscore and has the same name with the method, then add the ending `___` with no sense. Should I change `__to_dict__` to `__to_dict` for enhancement, or just remove this method?

Comment: Yes, removing the last two underscores would be better. You'd still have a potential conflict, as the method would still be externally accessible as `_DotDict__to_dict`, but it's rather unlikely to be a problem, and your current solution has the same problem with `__to_dict__`.

Comment: oh I just want to say 'with no conscious', not 'with no sense', sorry for my poor English.